# What is the best way to show incremental data in a gridview?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I am building a monitoring application. Data is presented to a user in a girdview. This data changes frequently(an application adds 5-6 entries every second). Total number of entires loaded may be a few thousand.

What is the best way to load these rows into gridview?

Should I load data incrementally? And add each row manually?

Or

Would calling DataBind again be too expensive?
I have noticed a flicker on screen with this approach and so don't want to use this.

Are there any better methods to populate a gridview with incremental data?

Comment: Depending on what kind of data you will be displaying...

Comment: To be honest, the best way to add this data will be whatever suits your client.  The requirement for what they need to be able to/want to view will determine the method used.

Comment: Small number of columns(less than 10), mostly text and numbers

Comment: Then , I suppose there won't be any problems.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the flicker caused by calling DataBind again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am building a monitoring application. Data is presented to a user in a grid view. This data changes frequently(an application adds 5-6 entries every second)

Can the human eye catch 5-6 updates a second? I think your good with one 
update every 500 ms.

Performance tips:

- Use BindingList or List. Stay away from datatable/dataset.
- Maintain a cache of all the updates. Use a timer with 500 ms
  interval, update the List datasource from the cache when interval elapses.
- Refresh the CurrencyManager and **do not rebind the grid**.

  CurrencyManager currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)this.BindingContext[Grid.DataSource];
      currencyManager.Refresh();

Answer (score 0):

I think loading data incrementally is much better option, and especial suits monitoring application.